# How to keep height of div fixed when it content changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that contains other divs. Something like this:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
   <div id='box1' class='boxes'></div>
   <div id='box2' class='boxes'></div>
   <div id='box3' class='boxes'></div>
</div>
```

by click on some buttons this happens:

```
changes function(num){
    $box="box"+num;
    $(".boxes").hide('fast');
    $("#"+$box).show('fast');

  };
```

or

```
  changes function(num){
    $box="box"+(num);
    $(".boxes").hide('fast',function(){
          $("#"+$box).show('fast');
    });

  }
```

css:

```
   html,body{height:100%};
  .boxes{dispaly:hidden};
   #box1{display:block};
```

when show and height happens the height of wrapper will change.
I want that the height of wrapper be fixed during show and hide is happening.
because the number of boxes is variable I can not set wrapper height for example: height=400px;
all boxes have equal height.

Comment: Have you tried `.wrapper { height: 400px;}` ? Should do the trick. Another option is `max-height: 400px;` This will let it shrink when the content doesn't need `400px`. The only other thing is to decide what happens with contents: `overflow:hidden` or default, which is `overflow: visible;`

Comment: all boxes have same height . i want during hiding of boxes the wrapper height doesn't change. on as you can see box1 is visible on page load.

Comment: If all boxes have equal height and the box1 will be always loaded then try to assign the height of the wrapper with the height of box1. `$('#wrapper').css("height", $('#box1').height());`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the event pipeline, you cannot portably and within the intended design of DOM rendering do what you are trying to do.  I think you want to suspend the resizing of the parent  while changing the viewable content within it on the assumption that the child  objects are same sized.

A relatively portable way to do this is to have a grandparent and parent div, place the child divs inline inside the parent and set your overflow to hidden so that you can position the parent div within the grandparent in JavaScript.

The appearance may be what you want, but you are banking on the size of the min width and height of the parent being set correctly, even at various magnifications and across web and mobile device displays.

Doing this properly requires skill and considerable cross browser testing.  It would be saner if you used a well tested JQuery or AngularJS component designed to give you something smooth.

Another way is to place the child  objects at the same location and vary the z position of them.  Use a solid background for the div.  This may be slightly simpler than the method in the previous two paragraphs.  You want to have no borders on the child  objects and the same background color for the parent as for the children.

Even this less complex solution may be unnecessary to make your page design clean and intuitive.   I recommend rethinking your design and conforming your presentation requirements to fit more closely with the built in DOM rendering features of the common browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my styles and script to:

```
.boxes{dispaly:hidden;min-width:100%};
 #box1{display:inline-block};
```

and

```
    $(".boxes").css('display','none');
    $("#"+$box).css('display','inline-block');
```

and it's working very well.